# Comparing MySQL dates in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, mysql, date

This is just a sanity check, but I've done several test cases before you all jump on the "down" button =]

I just want to check that comparing dates from a MySQL database in the format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` in JavaScript will work correctly. Unfortunately, I can't edit the query to return a Unix timestamp.

Example:

```
console.log('2010-05-22 00:54:12' > '2010-05-21 11:44:32');
```

All my test cases seem to suggest it works fine, but I just need to make sure.

Maybe my Google-fu is weak, but I can't find anything about it online. Does anyone know for sure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, I'm sure one reason they chose such a format was so you could do a standard string comparison on them.

Because the order of values is most-significant to least-significant, this will work perfectly fine as long as:

- The hour is in 24-hour time, and
- Any single digit value is preceded by a 0 (month, day, hour, etc.)

However do note that unless you standardize on a particular time zone (GMT for example), this will only accurately compare dates in a single time zone.

Comment: Cool, thanks. I'll give you a green tick in an hour or so in case anyone comes along to argue =]